# Unable to load one or more of the requested types. retrieve the loaderexceptions

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I've made up a small test app to demo the issue I'm trying to resolve.  I have a plugin architecture where the plugins derive from an interface.

Here's is the interface code:

```
namespace Test
{
  public interface ITestBase
  {
    int LifeTheUniverseAndEverything();
    bool Pessimist();
    bool Optimist();
  }
}
```

This builds to a .dll that is referenced by the main program solution and the plugin solution.

Here is the plugin code:

```
namespace Test
{
  public class TestPlugin : ITestBase
  {
    public int LifeTheUniverseAndEverything() { return 41; }
    public bool Pessimist() { return false; }
    public bool Optimist() { return true; }
  }
}
```

This produces a .dll that is dropped into a "plugins" folder off the main working directory.

Here's the main program.

```
namespace Test
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("testing...");
      string[] PluginFileLocs;
      try
      {
        string sWorkingDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        string sPluginDir = sWorkingDir + "\\Plugins";
        PluginFileLocs = Directory.GetFiles(sPluginDir, "*.dll");
        foreach (string plugin in PluginFileLocs)
        {
          Assembly theAssembly = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(plugin);
          foreach (Type type in theAssembly.GetTypes())
          {
            string aType = type.FullName;
            Console.WriteLine(aType);
          }
        }
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The issue is, that if the testplugin class derives off the ITestBase interface, the theAssembly.GetTypes throws an exception: unable to load one or more of the requested types. retrieve the LoaderExceptions.  Why, and how can I get my plugin to derive off an interface?

Comment: So you are likely getting a `ReflectionTypeLoadException`. What are the loader exceptions the message is telling you to check? The exception will have a property called `LoaderExceptions`. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.reflectiontypeloadexception.loaderexceptions.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the documentation for the Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom, it will not automatically load dependencies http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.reflectiononlyloadfrom.aspx

I'm guessing that's what's going on here.  Since your interface is defined in a separate assembly from the plugin, you must first load that assembly before trying to call GetTypes.

Comment: This was correct.  Switching from ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom to just LoadFrom fixed the behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Without further detail, it's hard to tell. My guess would be because you are loading it into a Reflection Only context by using `ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom`, which won't resolve dependencies, and the interface and plug ins are in different assemblies, you need to handle the `ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve` on the AppDomain, or don't load it in a reflection-only context.

Since you are likely to actually load your plug-in and execute them, it may be simplier to just load it completely. Best practice for plug ins is to load them in a different AppDomain and lock it down to keep the plug-in in a sandbox.